# ¿Cómo ocultar todos los collapse de bootstrap en una pagina?

Tags: php, bootstrap

Necesito ocultar todos los collapse de bootstrap en un página donde mediante un ciclo creo collapse y botones con id aleatorio.

```
foreach ($directories as $file){
   $aleatorio = rand(); // El aleatorio para el collapse

   echo '<a class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#demo'.$aleatorio.'">Mostrar/Ocultar</a>'; //Boton de collapse

   echo '<div id="demo'.$aleatorio.'" class="collapse in">'; //Div del collapse inicia
      echo $file[0];
   echo '</div>'; //Div del collapse finaliza }
```

Comment: Pude encontrar la respuesta a mi pregunta aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149923/bootstrap-initially-collapsed-element

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacer algo asi con jquery:

A tu boton le pones un id que va a ser leido por el scrip cuando le des click, al contenedor de los collapse le pones un id que va a ser el que toma el script para ocultar o mostrar.
Luego creas una variable como bandera para si es 0 quiere decir que las cosas no se estan mostrando, si es 1 es q estan a la vista y dsp jugas con eso, al dar click al boton pasas la variable a 1 y mostras el contenido del div y le cambias el texto para que ahora diga OCULTAR, cuando le volves a dar click pasas la variable a 0, ocultas el div y pasas el texto del boton a MOSTRAR

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<a href="#" id="show" class="btn">Click para Mostrar</a>
<br><br>
<div id="element" style="display: none;">
  



<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample1" aria-expanded="false"
aria-controls="collapseExample1">
  CLICK PARA ABRIR COLLAPSE UNO
</button>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample1">
  <div class="well">
 COLLAPSE UNO
  </div>
</div>

<br><br>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample2" aria-expanded="false" 
aria-controls="collapseExample2">
  CLICK PARA ABRIR COLLAPSE DOS
</button>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample2">
  <div class="well">
COLLAPSE DOS
  </div>
</div>

<br><br>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample3" aria-expanded="false"
aria-controls="collapseExample3">
  CLICK PARA ABRIR COLLAPSE TRES
</button>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample3">
  <div class="well">
 COLLAPSE TRES
  </div>
</div>


</div>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

  var estado = 0;

  $("#show").click(function(){

   if (estado == 0) {
    estado++
    $("#show").text("Click para Ocultar")
    $("#element").show();
   }
   else{
    estado--
    $("#show").text("Click para Mostrar")
    $("#element").hide();
   }

  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, pero no es lo que estoy buscando, yo puedo ocultar por defecto un div (del que conozca el id) con collapse, pero tengo un ciclo en el que creo los id aleatoriamente y lo que quiero es generalizar y que todos los collapse esten ocultos por defecto... Gracias nuevamente...

Comment: Proba metiendo todos los collapses dentro de un div y a ese div le pones el id de que oculte o no el contenido <div id="element" style="display: none;"> FUNCION QUE CREA TODOS LOS COLLAPSE </div>

Comment: Si eso no te sirve, subi por favor la estructura html donde reenderizas eso collapse para ver como los estas sumando al codigo y ahi va a ser mas facil guiarte

Comment: Tengo una funcion que dada una ruta busca los directorios y los archivos que tiene y por cada directorio ejecuta la misma funcion para buscar los directorios y archivos dentro de el y asi recursivamente pero el contenido de cada directorio lo pongo dentro de un div con id unico y lo muestro u oculto mediante un link a ese id, pero los quisiera todos por defecto ocultos y no como viene por defecto... No se si me hago entender...

Comment: Modifique mi respuesta, algo mas o menos asi? Si no vas a tener que buscar algo similar a lo que necesita sy mostrarlo o explicar mejor la pregunta porque me pierdo jaja

Comment: Imagina algo como esto https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/0ByGK pero que dentro de cada uno de las 4 diviciones existan mas collapses y asi recursivamente, pero que me aparescan absolutamente TODOS con estado "hide" (ocultos) y no conozco los id porque los otorgo aleatorios porque la cantidad de elementos collapse no es fija...

Comment: Pude encontrar la solución aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149923/bootstrap-initially-collapsed-element realmente algo muy sencillo de lo que no me percaté... Gracias...

Comment: Ah vos necesitabas que salgan todos pero todos cerrados por default, en la respuesta que cargue estaba eso si te fijas puse de mas que sean visibles o invisibles todos pero una vez que los pones visibles cada collapse esta cerrado y los tenes que abrir uno a uno.

Comment: Si no me había percatado porque pensaba que lo que hacía era ocultar y mostrar un div con todos los collapse...

Answer (score -1):

Valdría con quitar la clase *in* en el segundo *echo* (el del div) de cada iteración.

Esta clase indica si quieres mostrar el *collapse* abierto. Si no está, queda cerrado.

Yo al *id* no le pondría un aleatorio sino un secuencial, ya que se podría repetir.

Saludos.